# LocationListener not working, without any error in LogCat

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, locationlistener

im a bit desperate because somehow, my code just stopped working.

Code:

```
    public class MainBoard extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, LocationListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Location Listener
        current_location = new MarkerOptions();
        current_location.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location));
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
    }

//LocationListener
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("LocationListener", "LocationChanged");
     updateCurrentLocation(location);
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("LocationListener", "onProviderEnabled");
    instantiatePosition();
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("LocationListener", "onProviderDisabled");
    showGPSOfflineAlert();
}
}
```

I can't really see the error here, LogCat doesn't report any error, but no method is called, not even onProviderEnabled or onProviderDisabled...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you added required Permission into manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, i did. I have coarse location permission...